# Why does the theme of secondary site load the primary one in Wordpress Multisite?

Tags: theme-development, multisite

**I have this situation:**

1. I activated Multisite mode to develop the main website in a    secondary site with subdomain "beta";

> EX: www.mysite.com, beta.mysite.com

2. I duplicated the default theme with "beta" suffix, but it is not set    as a child theme;
3. every site has applied with the own respective theme.

> EX: *mysite-theme* for www.mysite.com, *mysite-beta* for beta.mysite.com

**The problem is:** when I visit the beta site, php files are loaded from *mysite-beta* as expected, but the css files are loaded from *mysite-theme*.

Why does happen this with Wordpress? How can solve this situation?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question with examples of site names and url's? I am having a hard time understanding your question.

Comment: I did it..I'm sorry for my bad English

Comment: OK, let me get it straight. So, in the `my sites` section of the wp-admin of your multisite network, you have two sites, `www.mysite.com`, and `beta.mysite.com`. You also set the primary site to be `beta.mysite.com`. Is this correct?

Comment: When you duplicated the theme, did you set the Theme Name and Theme URI in `style.css` to something new?

Comment: @Greeso I set the primary site 'www.mysite.com'

Comment: @WebElaine The themes have two different name and uri, respectively, name _My Site_ uri 'www.mysite.com' and name _My Site Beta_ uri 'beta.mysite.com'

Comment: In your beta theme's `functions.php` file double-check how your stylesheets are being enqueued. It's likely that the theme has a hard-coded path to `style.css` and you need to change the directory there.

Comment: @WebElaine in beta theme's `functions.php` there are not any enqueued stylesheets, they are loaded from `header.php` and more from static pages.

Comment: Aside from that being against best practices, you must have them coded to come from the "mysite-theme" folder rather than the "mysite-beta" theme folder. Subsites have all their own settings so it's not a setting problem but something within the theme that's coded to pull from the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test with the primary content I used `switch_to_blog(1);` in a main php page and it causes that the `get_header();` function loads the header page of blog **1** (in this case).

So, I added `restore_current_blog();` after searching contents with WP_Query and before calling `get_header();` and the theme works as I expect.

I omitted the function because I thought it is not necessary, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In the multisite backend dashboaord, in the top left corner, you have a `My Sites` link. Hover your mouse over it, and a dropdown will come up. The first option is `Network Admin`; click on it.

[image]

Once you are at the `Network Admin` section, you can manage your themes and sites.

You can add new themes and list all existing theme.

[image]

Note that if you click on `Installed Themes`, you will also have an option to `Network Enable` a theme for all sites.

[image]

In your case, **I would NOT enable any theme for all sites**. I would leave the theme disabled, then I would click on `Sites`, and you will see all your sites listed.

[image]

For each site, go to the `Theme` tab, enable the specific theme for that particular site.

[image]

Once you do so, you will be able to restrict the theme to the site.

Comment: I thank you for your answer, but I have already these settings applied as you suggested. I tried also to remove and add theme folders again.

Comment: @Rox - In this case, I suspect that you have "hard coded" file references in your themes. You are not making relative references to your files.

Comment: I found the problem! To test with the primary content I used `switch_to_blog(1);` in a php page and it causes the issue with the beta theme. So, I added `restore_current_blog();` after searching contents and the theme works as I expect. I omitted the function because I thought it is not necessary, but I was wrong.

Comment: Yay. Good luck.